# A question about permutation matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, permutation-groups, orthogonal-matrices, random-permutations

This question is trying to abstract out in a self-contained way the point that is probably being made in page 6 of this paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03544.pdf and why Theorem 4.1 there works.

Let $B$ be a $m \times m$ permutation matrix. This matrix keeps the $m-$dimensional all-ones vector invariant. Now lets say we choose a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ in which the all ones's vector is the first vector of a basis. *( It might be true that for the final argument to work this has to be an orthogonal basis but I am not sure!)* This then rewrites $B$ as matrix of the form, 
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
0 & \hat{B} \\ \end{bmatrix}$ where $\hat{B}$ is a $(m-1)-$dimensional matrix.

Now lets say that the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is $\{ e_1,..,e_m\}$. Then $B$ was permuting this basis in some way i.e for every $e_i$ there is an $e_j \neq e_i$ such that, $B e_i = e_j$. Now we look at the projections of this standard basis into the orthogonal subspace of the all ones vector ($\mathbf{1}_m \in \mathbb{R}^m$) i.e we look at the vectors, $\{ \hat{e}_1,..,\hat{e}_m \}$ where we define, $e_i = \langle e_i , \mathbf{1}_m\rangle \mathbf{1}_m + \hat{e}_i$. Then its clear that $\hat{B}\hat{e}_i = \hat{e}_j$.

So the vectors $\{ \hat{e}_1,..,\hat{e}_m \}$ form the vertices of a $(m-1)-$ simplex (``hyperoctahedron" is I guess also a name for this?) in the subspace orthogonal to the all ones vector and $\hat{B}$ causes a permutation of the vertices of this simplex.

- From this can it be concluded that $\hat{B}$ is an $(m-1)-$dimensional orthogonal matrix?

---

There are permutations of this $(m-1)-$ simplex i.e permutations of the set, $\{ \hat{e}_1,..,\hat{e}_m \}$ which cannot be implemented by in-plane rotations. I feel that if somehow we can rule out these permutations as candidates for $\hat{B}$ then we can conclude that $\hat{B} \in O(m-1)$. But I can't see a clear argument to do this. Intuitively this looks to be true : because if $\hat{B}$ were to cause these permutations then effectively $B$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^m$ also acts in a way which causes these permutations of this $(m-1)-$simplex which needs out-of-plane rotations for the simplex while at the same time keeping the vector $\mathbf{1}_m$ invariant and these two things cant be simultaneously true.

OR

Maybe a more direct way to explain is to say that since this $(m-1)-$dimensional simplex is in the invariant space of $\hat{B}$ the only permutations of the vertices of the simplex that it can induce are necessarily those that can be gotten by rotations and hence $\hat{B} \subset O(m-1)$. Can this be made 
rigorous?

Comment: It does indeed help to use an orthonormal basis for $mathbb{R}^{m}.$ Then the permutation matrix also leaves $v^{\perp}$ invariant, where $v$ is the all ones vector. Taking $w = \frac{v}{\sqrt{m}}$ as the first element of an orthonormal basis, and adjoining an orthonormal basis for $v^{\perp}$ to $\{w\},$ we obtain a new orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^{m}.$ Since permutation matrices are orthogonal matrices, it follows that the permutation matrix in question acts via  an orthogonal $(m-1) \times (m-1)$-matrix on the orthonormal basis for $\{v\}^{\perp}.$

Comment: If a linear map $T$ of $\mathbb R^m$ preserves the Euclidean norm and maps some subspace $S$ to itself, then it obviously also preserves the Euclidean norm on $S$, since the latter Euclidean norm is just the restriction to $S$ of the former. Now if we work with orthonormal bases for both $\mathbb R^m$ and for $S$, then the preceding observation tells us that, if $T$ is given by an orthogonal matrix, then so is the restriction $T\upharpoonright S$.

Comment: In my case what is the analogous "S" subspace you are thinking of?

Comment: The same as the space you were talking about, the orthogonal complement of the all-ones vector.